# How to pronounce "often"

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, spelling-pronunciations

At the website where people pronounce words from their languages, [the page for the word *often*](http://www.forvo.com/word/often/) gives 15 accounts. 13 people pronounced it with silent *t* (*ofen*), and only 2 with strong *t* (*ofTen*).

But all ESL teachers I know (U.S. native speakers) pronounce it with strong *t* (*ofTen*).

What is the right (standard) pronunciation?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This is very good question. I am not a native speaker nor a teacher, but I think that the more correct one is: "ofTen" - with the strong "T", but it's easier to pronounce it like "ofen", so therefore you hear it more "ofen" ;)

Comment: Pronunciation is a regional thing; there is no single right/correct way to pronounce *often* and nevermind the *t* there are multiple ways of pronouncing the *o* and the *e* as well.  I can tell you that in the areas of the US that I have lived, I'd never pronounce the *t* even if I were on my best "speaking behavior"

Comment: [Pronunciation of “often”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4470/pronunciation-of-often) ◊ [In what dialects does “often” rhyme with “soften”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20550/in-what-dialects-does-often-rhyme-with-soften) Please search the site before posting. It's in your own interest as it gets you the answer faster than typing up a whole question. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OED has

> Pronunciation:  Brit.  /ˈɒf(ə)n/ , /ˈɒft(ə)n/ , U.S. /ˈɔf(ə)n/ , /ˈɑft(ə)n/

I was taught (yes, really) that the Standard pronunciation did not have the *t* in the middle, and adding that in was dialectal. That's supported by OED's listing of [no *t*] before the version including *t*. Pronouncing the *t* isn't incorrect, though.